# Get rendered HTML of Page in Admin Area

Tags: wp-admin

In essence I want to mimic CouchCMS's ability to write custom Markup for a page and then dynamically add fields in the edit screen based on what should be editable.

[CouchCMS Documentation about what I mean](http://docs.couchcms.com/tutorials/portfolio-site/about-us.html#defining-editable-regions)

So I need a way to get the HTML output of the page in the Admin Area.

I tried

```
ob_start();
include get_page_template();
$content = ob_get_clean();
```

This is working BUT it's breaking the Admin Area because somehow including the template in the output buffer messes with some script includes it seems.

[image: Broken WordPress Admin Area]

I guess this is happening because of the `get_header()` and `get_footer()` calls in the included template. So maybe a way to turn them off would solve it. Or to just include the output without them.
But then I don't know whether the output is rendered correctly.

// EDIT:
Obligatory immediate idea after asking the question:

```
$content = file_get_contents(get_permalink());
```

This works, but only for public pages. But even then I guess you could send some Authentication Headers with the request and get access to that as well?
This is at least a quick workaround, but I'd like to not do it this way. So the original problem still exists.

Comment: This is just fundamentally not how WordPress works. Putting the full HTML of the page into the editor is not going to give you the result you want, even if it worked. If you want to have different areas of a template be editable you should implement custom fields. There's plugins like ACF that help with this.

Comment: I don't want to put the full HTML into the editor, just dynamically create MetaBoxes with the parts from the HTML that should be editable.
With ACF I could create a custom conditional that checks for the use of a specific custom template and then adds the MetaBoxes accordingly. That wouldn't be as dynamic as I hoped though. But I guess that's as close as I can get.